# Parallel calling a function in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++14

I have an `std::vector` of `std::function<void()>` like this:

```
std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> observers_;
```

calling each function like this:

```
for (const auto& obs : observers_.at(event)) obs();
```

I want to turn this into a parallel for loop. Since I am using `C++14`, and don't have access to the `std::execution::parallel` of `C++17`, I found a little library that allows me to create a ThreadPool.

How do I turn `for (const auto& obs : observers_.at(event)) obs();` into a version that calls each function in `observers_` in parallel? I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I tried, but this doesn't work.

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec = observers_.at(event);
ThreadPool::ParallelFor(0, vec.size(), [&](int i)
{
    vec.at(i);
});
```

The example program that uses the library below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

#include "ThreadPool.hpp"
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    std::mutex critical;
    ThreadPool::ParallelFor(0, 16, [&] (int i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(critical);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

The ThreadPool library.

```
#ifndef THREADPOOL_HPP_INCLUDED
#define THREADPOOL_HPP_INCLUDED

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ThreadPool {

public:

    template<typename Index, typename Callable>
    static void ParallelFor(Index start, Index end, Callable func) {
        // Estimate number of threads in the pool
        const static unsigned nb_threads_hint = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        const static unsigned nb_threads = (nb_threads_hint == 0u ? 8u : nb_threads_hint);

        // Size of a slice for the range functions
        Index n = end - start + 1;
        Index slice = (Index) std::round(n / static_cast<double> (nb_threads));
        slice = std::max(slice, Index(1));

        // [Helper] Inner loop
        auto launchRange = [&func] (int k1, int k2) {
            for (Index k = k1; k < k2; k++) {
                func(k);
            }
        };

        // Create pool and launch jobs
        std::vector<std::thread> pool;
        pool.reserve(nb_threads);
        Index i1 = start;
        Index i2 = std::min(start + slice, end);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i + 1 < nb_threads && i1 < end; ++i) {
            pool.emplace_back(launchRange, i1, i2);
            i1 = i2;
            i2 = std::min(i2 + slice, end);
        }
        if (i1 < end) {
            pool.emplace_back(launchRange, i1, end);
        }

        // Wait for jobs to finish
        for (std::thread &t : pool) {
            if (t.joinable()) {
                t.join();
            }
        }
    }

    // Serial version for easy comparison
    template<typename Index, typename Callable>
    static void SequentialFor(Index start, Index end, Callable func) {
        for (Index i = start; i < end; i++) {
            func(i);
        }
    }

};

#endif // THREADPOOL_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you should simply change:

```
vec.at(i); // Only returns a reference to the element at index i
```

into:

```
vec.at(i)(); // The second () calls the function
--- OR ---
vec[i](); // Same
```

Comment: Yes, after Barry pointed it out the rest was easy. Tired. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does this do?

```
vec.at(i);
```

What do you *want* it to do?

---

Unrelatedly, you're using `at()` when you mean `[]`.

Comment: Good point. I need a break. Still if I say ThreadPool::ParallelFor(0, vec.size(), [&] vec[i]);  i is not declared? How do I captuare what index I am at?

Answer (score -3):

This works:

```
ThreadPool::ParallelFor(0, (int)vec.size(), [&] (int i)
{
    vec[i]();
});
```

Comment: I am confused by the down votes. Is this an incorrect solution?